# FB Like btn losing hover state of parent in IE

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, hover, facebook-like

I have a box, when hover, a div comes up with 3 buttons. One of them is the FB Like Btn. 
All works fine in FF, Chrome, Opera.

In IE (7+): when hover the FB Like btn the entire div (parent) is losing hover state. it seems that parts of the FB btn are transparent.

Anyone had the same problem? 
Thanks!

---update:
sometimes I get the "cannot load" icon instead of the FB like btn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

couldn't think of anything else than to use a

```
$(".class").mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).addClass('hover');
});
$(".class").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

everything wrapped in a function to detect my browser. 
hope it helps